# How (or is it possible) to run code inside of /etc/network/interfaces?

Tags: networking, interface

The task: generate random mac when an interfaces comes up.

```
#this does work to generate a random mac
echo '00 60 2f'$(od -An -N3 -t xC /dev/urandom) | sed -e 's/ /:/g'
```

the inside of /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
    #This works:
    hw-mac-address aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
    #while this does not when I ifup eth0:
    hw-mac-address $(echo '00 60 2f'$(od -An -N3 -t xC /dev/urandom) | sed -e 's/ /:/g')
```

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Look into ´pre-up´/´post-up´ in ´man interfaces´.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found multiple solutions. 1 of them is with pre-up, (Thansk fkraiem)

This requires that macchanger is installed.
/etc/network/interfaces looks like this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
pre-up macchanger -m `echo '00 60 2f'$(od -An -N3 -t xC /dev/urandom) | sed -e 's/ /:/g'` $IFACE
```

The second solution is the correction of my originally incorrect configuration.
This solution *doesn't* require that macchanger is installed

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
hwaddress ether `echo '00 60 2f'$(od -An -N3 -t xC /dev/urandom) | sed -e 's/ /:/g'`
```